# Not able to load image

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor, .net-core

I am trying to keep the image path value in a variable and pass it to img src property, but its not working.

Below is my code...

```
<div class="js-container-assortmentlist">
  @{
    string layoutImage1 = "FORMULE1UNTIL3_MOBIELETAFEL1_A_SIDE.jpg";
    string layoutImage2 = "FORMULE1UNTIL3_MOBIELETAFEL1_B_SIDE.jpg";
    string imageSource1 = "~/images/TafelLayouts/" + layoutImage1;
    string imageSource2 = "~/images/TafelLayouts/" + layoutImage2;    
  }

  <div style="width:30%; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display:block " id="layoutImage1">
    <img class="" id="imgLayout" src="@imageSource1" alt="@layoutImage1">
  </div>
  <div style="width:30%; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display:none " id="layoutImage2">
    <img class="" id="imgLayout" src="@imageSource2" alt="@layoutImage2">
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

When I am providing the value for img src directly like "~/images/TafelLayouts/FORMULE1UNTIL3_MOBIELETAFEL1_A_SIDE.jpg" itsworking fine.

As i need to load dynamic images , so I need to pass this value dynamically.

Comment: call a method in image src like src="<%=getImagePath()%>" and return your image path from the specified js method, or go for Url Content , or for dynamic scr change just go for $("#imageid").src="your image path";

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Url.Content` to correct translate `~/`

```
  @{
    string layoutImage1 = "FORMULE1UNTIL3_MOBIELETAFEL1_A_SIDE.jpg";
    string layoutImage2 = "FORMULE1UNTIL3_MOBIELETAFEL1_B_SIDE.jpg";
    string imageSource1 = Url.Content("~/images/TafelLayouts/" + layoutImage1);
    string imageSource2 = Url.Content("~/images/TafelLayouts/" + layoutImage2);    
  }
```

To get url dynamically you may create a custom UrlHelper on your project

```
namespace project.MyCustomExtensions

public static class UrlHelperExtensions
  {
      public static string ImageUrl(this UrlHelper url, string param1, string param2)
      {
          // your logic goes here 
      }
  }
```

An them call it like this

```
@using project.MyCustomExtensions // using on top of your view

// your html code

<img class="" id="imgLayout" src="@Url.ImageUrl("someParamValue", "otherParamValue")" alt="@layoutImage2">
```